# SSH session termination due to lost internet connectivity causes the running process to terminate as well

Tags: linux, ssh, centos6, nohup

I am running a long running process using nohup . I invoke a script using an alias with the following format in CentOS 6.5

I do this because the process I am running takes about a week to complete , however I noticed that as soon as my SSH session terminates(due to internet connection) my process terminates as well even though I am using nohup , can someone let me know what might be a problem ?

```
alias submithadoopjob='/opt/dfconfig/scripts/hadoopscripts/submithadoopjob > /tmp/hadoop.log 2>&1 &'
```

Then I just call the alias submithadoopjob and I can see the log being generated in the log file hadoop.log (using tail) that I am redirecting the sysout to.

Comment: what is content of submithadoopjob file

Comment: @Rahul a command to execute jar file that is being executed

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) or [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) so that you can easily resume the session when you reconnect.

Comment: Thanks I will try that , I thought using nohup to run the process in the backgroud while tailing to a log file of that process  would suffice though, is it not the case?